# google tag manager and callbacks

Tags: javascript, google-tag-manager

Ok so I'm driving myself crazy with this problem.

I have a photo gallery that fades and image out then fades a new one in on a button press.  I'm trying to get the new photo that fades in to send to google tag manager.  I have some code that gets the new photo, but because it's an asynchronous function and the outer function finishes before the callback.

It's for google tag manager so I has to be inside an anonymous function and return a value.  Any Ideas would be helpful.

Here's the code:

```
function(){
var gallery = document.getElementsByClassName("myclass")[0];
var newPhoto = "no Photo";
var mytransition = "";

    var t;
    var el = document.createElement('fakeelement');
    var transitions = {
      'transition':'transitionend',
      'OTransition':'oTransitionEnd',
      'MozTransition':'transitionend',
      'WebkitTransition':'webkitTransitionEnd'
    }

    for(t in transitions){
        if( el.style[t] !== undefined){
        mytransition = transitions[t];
        }
    }

var transitionEvent = mytransition;
transitionEvent && gallery.addEventListener(transitionEvent, function() {
    var newgallery = document.getElementsByClassName("myclasse");
    var image_link = newgallery[0].getElementsByTagName("a")[0];  
    var returnText = "Position: 0 Image: " + image_link.attributes["href"].value;
     newPhoto = returnText;
});

return newPhoto;
}
```

Comment: Why does it have to be in an anonymous function?

Comment: Because tag manager requires it for their custom javascript.

Comment: Does tag manager require it as an anonymous function? Can you give an example of its usage in google tag manager. That should help.

Comment: This field should be a JavaScript function that returns a value using the 'return' statement. If the function does not explicitly return a value, it will return undefined and your container may not behave as expected. Below is an example of this field:
  function() {
    var now = new Date();
    return now.getTime();
  }